# Slow Application performance

Tags: android, multithreading

I have developed a Contacts application. It does everything that a normal contacts application should does. There is always a chance of improvement. I had noticed in Android Emulator that loading for contact images starts when user has settled, he has scrolled the contact list to the area where there are chances are good that he would get contact he is searching for. So, I tried to implement the same thing on my app copy. I have implemented it. Its running very very slow. As I presume, I believe that application is running the thread multiple time even if it has retrieved the image which leads to big lagging. I am aware of the ASync task but just out of curiosity and to check whether it can be done, I don't wish to implement it here. Here is the source code for MainActivity.

```
package com.example.contact;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;



import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.Contacts;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    ListView listview;
    private boolean mPaused;
    private MyAdapter mAdapter;
    private View view;
    private boolean running = false;
    final private ArrayList<String> con_ids = new ArrayList<String>();
    private Context context;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        listview = getListView();
        context = this;

        Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, 
                                              null, 
                                              null, 
                                              null, 
                                              ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME+" ASC");


        if(c!=null)
        {
            for(c.moveToFirst();!c.isAfterLast();c.moveToNext()){
                con_ids.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID)));
            }
        }

        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, con_ids);
        listview.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        listview.setOnScrollListener(makeScrollListener());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        mPaused = !enabled;
    }

    private AbsListView.OnScrollListener makeScrollListener() {
        return new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView absListView, int scrollState) {
                setEnabled(scrollState != AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL);
                running = false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView absListView, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                String log = "";
                Log.d(log, "Scroll First Item" + i);
                Log.d(log, ""+ listview.getChildCount());           

                final int want = i;
                running = true;

                runOnUiThread(new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    int totalChild = listview.getChildCount();
                    int first = listview.getFirstVisiblePosition() - listview.getHeaderViewsCount();
                    int toRetrieve = want-first;
                    int id;
                    long con_id;
                    Bitmap thumbnail;
                    final ListView list = listview;

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        while(running)
                        {
                            if(!(toRetrieve<0||toRetrieve>=totalChild))
                            {
                                id = want+toRetrieve;
                                con_id = Long.valueOf(con_ids.get(id));
                                Uri ContactUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, con_id);
                                InputStream stream = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(context.getContentResolver(), ContactUri);
                                thumbnail = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
                                if(thumbnail == null)
                                {
                                    toRetrieve++;
                                    continue;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    View view = list.getChildAt(toRetrieve);
                                    if(view == null)
                                    {
                                        toRetrieve++;
                                        continue;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        ImageView iamge = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.contact_iamge);
                                        iamge.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
                                    }
                                    toRetrieve++;
                                }

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                running = false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }));
            }
        };
    }

}
```

Code for MyAdapter,

```
package com.example.contact;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.Contacts;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebView.FindListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private Context context;
    private ListView listview;
    private ArrayList<String> ids;
    private LayoutInflater infl;
    private String displayname;
    private String maindetail;
    private SimplifiedContact contact;
    private Drawable drawable;


    public MyAdapter(Context context, int ResourceId, ArrayList<String> list)
    {
        super(context, ResourceId, list);
        this.context = context;
        ids = list;
        infl = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        drawable = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.person);
    }

    static class ViewHolder
    {
        public ImageView image;
        public TextView display_name;
        public TextView main_detail;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View row = convertView;
        contact = new SimplifiedContact(context, Long.valueOf(ids.get(position)));

        if(row == null)
        {
            row = infl.inflate(R.layout.single_cell, parent, false);
            ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

            viewHolder.display_name =(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.disp_name);
            viewHolder.main_detail = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.main_detail);
            viewHolder.image = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.contact_iamge);
            row.setTag(viewHolder);

        }

        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
        holder.display_name.setText(contact.getDisplayName());
        holder.main_detail.setText(contact.getMainDetail());
        holder.image.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);

        return row;
    }


}
```

I wish to know, how this lag can be reduced. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Before spawning a thread in runOnUiThread(). I used normal thread procedure, resulting into a exception that the main thread which originally created the view, can be the only one to modify it. I googled for solution and learnt that to make things better, I would have to run the thread on UI thread.

Comment: Well, I have had implemented ASync Task in my Application. It is just I do not want to do it this time. So, basically, in this problem, do I need to abort this onScroll load concept ?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to take that Thread instance that you are making in runOnUiThread and put It in a field, initializing It in the onCreate. I think that you are creating several thread instaces with no use.

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

ListView listview;
private boolean mPaused;
private MyAdapter mAdapter;
private View view;
private boolean running = false;
final private ArrayList<String> con_ids = new ArrayList<String>();
private Context context;
Thread uiThread;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    listview = getListView();
    context = this;

    Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, 
                                          null, 
                                          null, 
                                          null, 
                                          ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME+" ASC");


    if(c!=null)
    {
        for(c.moveToFirst();!c.isAfterLast();c.moveToNext()){
            con_ids.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID)));
        }
    }

    uiThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        int totalChild = listview.getChildCount();
        int first = listview.getFirstVisiblePosition() - listview.getHeaderViewsCount();
        int toRetrieve = want-first;
        int id;
        long con_id;
        Bitmap thumbnail;
        final ListView list = listview;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            while(running)
            {
                if(!(toRetrieve<0||toRetrieve>=totalChild))
                {
                    id = want+toRetrieve;
                    con_id = Long.valueOf(con_ids.get(id));
                    Uri ContactUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, con_id);
                    InputStream stream = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(context.getContentResolver(), ContactUri);
                    thumbnail = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
                    if(thumbnail == null)
                    {
                        toRetrieve++;
                        continue;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        View view = list.getChildAt(toRetrieve);
                        if(view == null)
                        {
                            toRetrieve++;
                            continue;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ImageView iamge = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.contact_iamge);
                            iamge.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
                        }
                        toRetrieve++;
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    running = false;
                }
            }
        }
    });

    mAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, con_ids);
    listview.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    listview.setOnScrollListener(makeScrollListener());
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    mPaused = !enabled;
}

private AbsListView.OnScrollListener makeScrollListener() {
    return new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView absListView, int scrollState) {
            setEnabled(scrollState != AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL);
            running = false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView absListView, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            String log = "";
            Log.d(log, "Scroll First Item" + i);
            Log.d(log, ""+ listview.getChildCount());           

            final int want = i;
            running = true;

            runOnUiThread(uiThread);
        }
    };
}
```

}

Comment: My Primary Objective is to start the thread when user has stopped scrolling and stopping it again when scrolls again. I see no better place. However, I welcome your suggestion, Please clarify your answer with code sample, it would be helpful.

Comment: Your code above doesn't really change anything about the app and will run just as slow, because it's still the exact same code running on the UI thread.